# Allow Content Editor Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, cewp

Using SharePoint 2007, how could I allow the adding of CEWP's to the selection menu of an "Add a Web Part" dialog while in Edit Page mode? As of the moment, I can only add Announcements, Calendar, Links, Shared Documents, Tasks but I do not have the ability to add a CEWP. I have full access to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At Site Settings > Site Features > Site Collection Features, you will want to have the Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure set to active.

Then, on the site, go to Site Settings > Site Features, and activate the Office SharePoint Server Publishing feature. You should then be able to add the content editor web part to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Quite often I see SharePoint 2010 websites without the Content Editor webpart (MSContentEditor.dwp)

To enable this web part you need to activate the BasicWebParts feature on that site. I did not find an option to do this by the web site admin; you can enable the feature however by using SharePoint powershell.

Execute the following statement in the SharePoint Powershell and the Content editor web part will be added to your site

Enable-SPFeature 00bfea71-1c5e-4a24-b310-ba51c3eb7a57 -Url [SharepointSiteUrl]

To get the SharePoint site url just run

Get-SPSite

[Gertjanvanmontfooort blog](http://gertjanvanmontfoort.blogspot.no/2014/06/missing-content-editor-web-part-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in SharePoint 2010, but I couldn't see other webparts due to my user permissions on the Site Collection. After getting "Restricted Read" rights on the Site Collection I could see all of the different WebParts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what helped me fo **Sharepoint 2013 Online** (**Office365**):
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/problems-opening-a-site-from-sharepoint-designer/d1e71427-be3f-4ea7-be3b-8ba6b64af76c?page=2&auth=1

Basically, I had to set flag DenyAddAndCustomizePages to 0 using sharepoint power shell.

Moreover, from time to time I had to reset the flag to 0 as the online sharepoint seems to reset it to deafult 1.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the above, and other proposed solutions, my eventual success was through PowerShell script. Admittedly I did check that Custom Scripts was permitted and I did have to Activate the two "SharePoint Server Publishing" features described above, but as I am using a sub-site I presmume something else must have been messed up. In the end the following script allowed me to see the Content Editor option when adding a Web Part:
SET-SPOSite  -DenyAddandCustomizePages 0

The full article can be found here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/problems-opening-a-site-from-sharepoint-designer/d1e71427-be3f-4ea7-be3b-8ba6b64af76c?page=2&auth=1